# auto generate primary key with specific format in java and database

Tags: sql-server

Hi guys here is my question i have a form that have auto increment primary key with specific format

in the input text i enter the year in inputText so the primary key must have that year/autoincrement number;

example :

if i enter in the year field 2018 in database i should find like 2018/1 in its primary key  .

here is the code :

```
public static AtomicInteger genId = new AtomicInteger(1);

public void generer(){
   Be be = new Be();
   be.setBrenSeq(anneeSeq + "/" + genId.getAndIncrement());
   be.setBrenAnnee(anneeSeq);
   ejbFacade.create(be);
}
```

can someone please help i don't know how to do it .

Comment: This question is at most JPA or JDBC related, not java-se  or jsf. I removed those tags, please add the correct ones

Comment: yeah it is jpa and ejb sorry i forgot it

Comment: This is not a very good way to handle primary keys. Your format here is violating 1NF by sticking multiple pieces of information into a single column. In this case you have the year the row was inserted and the number of inserts for that year. That should be two columns, not one. And really you should use date or datetime to store date information.